# Should conference abstracts be included in profiles on sites like ResearchGate and Google Scholar?

Tags: publications, cv, google-scholar

I think it depends on the field. in physics i don't see it as much, whereas in life sciences it is quite popular.

Is it cluttering the profile of a postdoc applicant (let's say in biophysics)?

Comment: Just to clear, you are specifically talking about conference presentations/posters where there is no full-text publication? I think it's important to distinguish between conferences that result in an archived full-text publication and those that do not.

Comment: "should"? no idea, but a lot of people do it and both mentioned pages have labels for conference abstracts and such when you add new information to them.